# First 2 cookies work, third does not

Tags: php, cookies, session-variables

This has got me puzzled, and although it's likely an oversight, I need some fresh eyes please.

```
session_start();

if( !isset( $_COOKIE['cookie1'] ) ) {

  if( !isset ( $_GET['getvar1'] ) ) {

    $_SESSION['var1'] = 0;

  } else {

      $var1 = (int) $_GET['getvar1'];

      $_SESSION['var1'] = $var1;

      setcookie('cookie1', $var1, ( time() + 604800 ), '/', '.domain.com', false, true );
  }

} else {

    $_SESSION['var1'] = $_COOKIE['cookie1'];

}
```

First several work [cookie(n)/getvar(n)/var(n)], but then the next doesn't work. I copied the first statement twice, renaming – which was the first place I checked and had checked by another colleague.

I've even checked some of the sites that check where you are on your cookie limits and still nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: `$_SESSION['var1']` instead of `$_SESSION[var1']`?

Comment: you forget to add seesion_start() http://lt1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Thank, I forgot to mention what I thought would be obvious and have updated the original code.

Comment: What are the urls you are calling?